# Are Windows services considered micro-services?

Tags: windows-services, microservices

I have a Windows service that listens on a queue; when there is a new message, it parses it, and stores it in its own storage.

It's "uni-directional" in  the sense that it just listens on a queue, but doesn't expose any endpoint and it doesn't interact with other services.

Is this considered a micro-service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name implies any service which is not monolithic, which can be independently built and deployable can be a microservice.

There is 12 factor approach to be called a true micro service, https://www.nginx.com/blog/microservices-reference-architecture-nginx-twelve-factor-app/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a article about that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/microservices

> Services communicate with each other by using well-defined APIs.
>   Internal implementation details of each service are hidden from other
>   services.